# Не записывается информация в Form1.designer.cs

Tags: c#

В C# не записываются строки:

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
this.textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_TextChanged);
this.textBox1.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.textBox1_KeyPress);
```

в Form1.designer.cs. Приходится записывать вручную.

Comment: @Mr-Al, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 2):

Похоже, что-то падает внутри дизайнера при сохранении.

Причины могут быть следующие

- Вы используете платные компоненты без лицензии или качественного крека
- Вы используете компоненты с неправльными настройками (например, в настройках `DevExpress` есть галочка "Разрешить визуальное наследование", без которой унаследованные компоненты не сохраняют изменения, сделанные с ними в унаследованных классах).
- Вы используете свои компоненты, в которых в нужных местах не стоит проверка на DesignMode, в результате чего они лезут туда, куда из дизайнера нет доступа.
- Иногда бывают проблемы при слишком большой вложенности контролов. Чаще всего они возникают при работе со сплиттерами (не знаю почему, просто такая глючная штука).

Answer (score 0):

Я честно не понял, как у вас это получилось. Вы можете создать событие программно, тогда в form1.cs (не в дизайнере) вы должны написать что-то вроде того:

```
button1.Click += (s, e) =>
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException(); // тут что-то делаете
                };
```

Поясните пожалуйста, что вы конкретно делали, что у вас не появились EventHandler-ы.
А дизайнер не трогайте вообще, иначе каждый раз будете туда заново все дописывать. :)